# Can no longer ignore certificate errors during publishing in VS2012

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, ssl-certificate, msdeploy

I've been using the MSDeploy publishing service from Visual Studio to publish my projects.  The publishing URL is https://machinename.domain.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd.  It worked fine in VS2010 -- I was able to check a checkbox that said ignore certificate errors.  That box is no longer shown in VS 2012.  I found a post indicating that I'm supposed to get prompted about whether to ignore certificate errors -- but I'm not and I can no longer publish my project.  Any ideas?

Comment: The certificate error dialog box should have Reject and Accept buttons, and if you click Accept it should ignore the error. Are you not getting that dialog box?  It should also have a "save this certificate for future sessions of VS" check box so you only have to click Accept once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your publish profile from `/Properties/PublishProfiles/<Profile>.pubxml` and add the following line within the `PropertyGroup` element:

```
<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet because today it started working -- I think because I installed one of the self-signed certs in the store.  But I can swear it wasn't working yesterday...  This looks like the right answer though.  Thanks so much!